# What's wrong with my code in c++?

Tags: c++

This is the code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring> 
using namespace std;
class Headquarter
{
private:
    //num of total warriors
    int totalNum;
public:
int getTotalNum() ;

};
int Headquarter::getTotalNum()
{   return totalNum;    }
int main()
{
    Headquarter a;
    Headquarter *p =&a;
    cout << (p->getTotalNum) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I can't compile it with g++,4.8.4. I don't konw what's wrong with it.
This is the wrong message:

```
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:19:7: error: no match for ‘operator<<’ (operand types are                             std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}’ and ‘<unresolved>`overloaded function type>’)
```

cout << (p->getTotalNum) << endl;
       ^

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
cout << (p->getTotalNum) << endl;
```

`getTotalNum` is a class method. Therefore it must be invoked like any other function:

```
cout << (p->getTotalNum()) << endl;
```

Comment: Thanks!You really helped me a lot!